real time redirect in next.config.mjs
I'm new in Nextjs. I created redirect paths with ajax in next.config.mjs.
But when I changes redirect paths I should rebuild my project once again.
I want redirect new paths without build.
`async redirects() {
    let data = await getRedirectsFromApi();
    if (data.length > 0) {
    } else {
      data = [
        {
          source: "/en/product/:id/:slug",
          destination: "/product/:id/:slug",
          permanent: true
        },
      ];
    }
    // console.log(data)
    return data;
  },`

